# Render transparent bottle in threejs

Tags: three.js

I have created bottle in blender. If i test it on threejs editor it is giving right results.
[image]

But when I render it on my site it is giving
[image]

This as output. I am but new to threejs

```
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'



const updateAllMaterials = () =>
{
    scene.traverse((child) =>
    {
        if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
        {
            child.material.envMap = environmentMap
            child.material.transparent = true
            child.material.opacity = 0.1
            child.material.envMapIntensity = 5

            const material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                transmission: 1, // use material.transmission for glass materials
                opacity: 0.2,
                color:"blue",
                transparent: true
            } );
            child.material = material
        }
    })
}

// Canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas.webgl')

const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader()
gltfLoader.load('/models/wine5.glb',(bottle)=>{
    bottle.scene.scale.set(0.5,0.45,0.5)
    bottle.scene.rotation.set(-0.5,1,0.3)
    bottle.scene.position.set(-1,-1.5,2)
    updateAllMaterials()
    scene.add(bottle.scene)

})

// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene()
const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper( 5 );
scene.add( axesHelper );

const directionalLights = new THREE.PointLight('#fff',4)
directionalLights.position.set(-0.4,2,5)
scene.add(directionalLights)



/**
 * Sizes
 */
const sizes = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
}


/**
 * Camera
 */
// Base camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
scene.add(camera)

// ENV MAPS

const  singleTextureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader()

singleTextureLoader.load('/BG/tree.jpg',(img)=>{
    scene.background = img
})



/**
 * Renderer
 */
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas,
    antialias: true
})
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding
renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping
renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1
renderer.depth = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `updateAllMaterials()` is traversing an empty scene, thus not applying the material to anything. Just swap the calls like this:

```
scene.add(bottle.scene)
updateAllMaterials()
```

Also, inside the `updateAllMaterials()` function, you are changing some parameters of the child's material, and then you overwrite the material itself, losing all the changes.

It should be something like this:

```js
const material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({
    transmission: 1,
    opacity: 0.2,
    color:"blue",
    transparent: true,
    envMap: environmentMap,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.1,
    envMapIntensity: 5
});
child.material = material
```